# What kind of breadboard and prototyping board do I need for this right-angle DB25 connector?

Tags: pcb, soldering, pcb-assembly

What kind of breadboard and prototyping board do I need to fit this right-angle DB25 connector?

I'm new to soldering and don't know what the standards are. Additional information on this subject would  be helpful as well.

[image: DB25 right-angle connector]

Comment: The pins are not on a 2.54mm pitch so you'll either have to get a breakout board as suggested below by @MichaelK (+1)or solder wires to the pins and stick them in the breadboard holes. If you only need a few (eg. Tx, Rx, GND) connections the latter may be easier than sourcing a PCB.  You could use short bare wires or longer solid-conductor insulated wires.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany Best suggestion - also worth noting that using the thicker square pins in a breadboard can make that hole loose and intermittent if you later want to insert a thin lead like a signal diode. Take jumpers with pins intended for breadboard use, cut them in half - two wires ready made for adapting off-pitch connectors.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you are searching for is a DB25 breadboard adapter, looking like this:

[image]

Website (example): [Example](https://www.winford.com/products/pbc25.php)

They also exist in a smaller (double row) format like [on this website](https://store.qkits.com/technological-arts/d-sub-adapters-25-pin-socket-addb25s-ra.html)

[image]

Comment: As a note, these kinds of boards are fairly easy to make, but for some components can be a nightmare to track down. I recommend you invest some time in learning how to make adapter/breakout boards, it will save you a lot of frustrations down the road.

Answer (score 5):

That type of staggered pins *are* more or less standard because they must also fit straight-through DB-25 footprints which are standardized, but you need a protoboard that is designed to hold them. This image was the first I found on google, but you can find them in all shapes and forms. This is for DB-9. Note the odd staggered part to the right:

[image]

Since the normal protoboard spacing is 2.54 mm while the DB-25 pin spacing is 2.77 mm, you need to search for a dedicated DB-25 protoboard. It could be easier to buy an adapter board which includes the correct connector, but have pins or screw terminals at a more convenient spacing.

Comment: Do breadboards exists for this pin spacing? Also, what is the correct spacing for me to look for?

Comment: @Zhro I've updated the answer. If it is still unclear, keep asking here and I'll clarify if I can.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is that you could find an old ISA prototyping breadboard with 1 or 2 DB-25 connector pads. The advantage of this breadboard is the size of the breadboard available for you circuitry. Thought is was designed for PCB compatible ISA slots the connect is easy to find and you could wire it for your own use.

Radio Shack used to sell them but I believe I have seen them around on sites that sell surplus electronics from time to time.