# Are there blank prototype PCBs with staggered edges for a DB25 connector?

Tags: pcb, soldering, pcb-assembly

Are there blank prototype PCB boards I can buy that will accept a solderable DB25 with its staggered pins?

[image: edge connector with db25]

Comment: Probably not, but you might possibly be able to fake it by offsetting the contacts from the pads on both sides to compromise.   A better solution could be to get a DB25 to dual row header cable as it typically used for PC ports on motherboards or internal connectors on cards, and put a dual row header on your protoboard

Comment: See also https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/393267/what-kind-of-breadboard-and-prototyping-board-do-i-need-for-this-right-angle-db2 or search for db25 prototyping boards - but mostly they are designed for PCB mount bd25 rather than wedging a solder-bucket one on the side.

Comment: Or use single-sided board and run wires from the other side up.

Comment: You could learn to design your own board. A 50mm x 50mm board would probably do it.